# iPhone sdk Zoom in/out

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to create a app having zoom in/out on image .So anyone say the delegates for zoom.

Thanks in advance,

BrightRaj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Create a ScrollView
Then Set the maximumZoomScale and minimumZoomScale.
Then return the image by using this delegate

```
-viewForZoomingInScrollView:
```

And then use this method

```
-scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:
```

to do what action you want when zooming.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `UIScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

Place your image over UIScrollView..

Handle the zoom function using the delegate

```
– zoomToRect: animated:
```

Answer (score 0):

See zoomin and zoomout of pdf file

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010281-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2